# Wavelet Packet Transform vs Discrete wavelet transform vs Continuous wavelet transform

Tags: signals, signal-processing, wavelet, wavelet-transform

Can someone explain, what is the difference between DWT, CWT, and WPT please?

I am confident I understand the difference between DWT and CWT, a DWT is an essentially a CWT with restrictions on what the coefficients can be, but I'm totally confused by WPT. What's the "packet" on about? Are they the same thing just a different name?

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out.

WPT is a DWT, but continues to filter both the high AND low frequency components. DWT only filters the low frequency at higher levels.